# substring is changed by substringof?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, substring, odata

I found OData filter string function `bool substring(string p0, string p1)` while reading [MCSD Certification Toolkit (Exam 70-483)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118612094) book.

Trying to use it in my application:

```
/Categories?$select=CategoryName&$filter=substring(CategoryName,'Seafood')
```

And got error:

```
No function signature for the function with name 'substring' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: 

    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32); 
    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32 Nullable=true);
    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32, Edm.Int32); 
    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32 Nullable=true, Edm.Int32); 
    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32, Edm.Int32 Nullable=true); 
    substring(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.Int32 Nullable=true, Edm.Int32 Nullable=true).
```

Looks like required substring function is gone? Where it is?

I found similar function that works nice:

```
/Categories?$select=CategoryName&$filter=substringof(CategoryName,'Seafood')
```

Comment: substring exists but does not take 2 strings in parameter: `string substring(string p0, int pos)` or `string substring(string p0, int pos, int length)`

Comment: Going through the MSDN documentation, `substring` never took two `String` objects as parameters. Are you sure that this isn't simply a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Because of This reason:

`substringof()` is a **V3** function while `contains()` is a **V4** function.

Try contains now:

```
$filter=contains(Name,'King')
```

See [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25006080/edit)